# Restrict a speech recognition to only one language

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I have been trying to make a speech recognizer to recognize only the selected language each time but it seems that the english language is always mixed in between, thus creating inconsistencies. For example, speaking in a different language than english and what you said in that language might be "misheard" by the device, bringing up something random in english.
This is how I have been trying to do so far:

```
        final SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this); //Creating SpeechRecognizer
        final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        switch (languageSelection) {
            case "En":
                callSpeechBtn();
                break;
            case "Gr":
                speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "el-GR");
                callSpeechBtn();
                break;
            case "local":
                speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                callSpeechBtn();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I am assuming you want the language recognizer to only listen in on language X and not on anything in between. The problem is that without recognizing the other language (and translating it propely) it has no idea what this other language is,

Comment: There's no way to do that.  What you'd want would be another level of intelligence-  it would need to know that what they said wasn't english, correctly figure out when they switch, and correctly figure out when they switch back.  That's several steps beyond what current implementations can do, and its not really something I think any are going for-  its a very unusual request.  You're looking at writing your own recognizer to even attempt that.